# access dynamically generated nested object name

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dynamically-generated

I'm creating a nested object with random characters dynamically on page load. I can't figure out how to access the names dynamically.  I'm using a library that needs the name of these objects to trigger its functions.

'makeid()' is function that generates characters to form a string.

The return will give an object.

code snip:

```
    var setTiledLayer = function(URL, lyrNm) {
      var temp = makeid();
      lyrHldr[temp] = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(URL, {id: lyrNm});
      return lyrHldr[temp];
    };
```

Comment: With "names" you mean "properties"?

Comment: I want to access the newly created sub object ex. makeid(); = asdfj; // lyrHldr['asdfj'] = .....